How to open http://localhost in the currently open chrome browser when I run my Flutter Web project?
Running the following command helps me build and run my project.
flutter run --debug -d chrome --target=lib/main_development.dart --web-port=64146

The issue I’m facing is that Flutter launches a new Chrome browser to display the app. Since this is a company laptop with strict policies, I can’t create a new profile or must log in to my profile every time I run the app, which is quite frustrating. This is especially inconvenient because I already have an open browser where I’m logged in.
Note: Although I can copy and paste the localhost URL into a new tab in the open browser, it isn’t connected to Flutter, so I can’t debug or view logs!
So, this is my question: Is there anything I need to add to the command to force Flutter to open the http://localhost: in the current open browser (existing Profile)?


https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79647#issuecomment-812777355 this comment may help you.

@thenry thank you for the link. Modifying Flutter’s source files is risky and can break updates. I will probably create a feature request on their side.

I added the feature request here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/159852

I have a bit of a workaround using flutter web-server, if all you want to do is view logs than view my answer below.

A temporary workaround while waiting for the feature request is to deploy your flutter application as a standalone web-server:
flutter run -d web-server

You will get a command line response:
lib/main.dart is being served at http://localhost:11111

Now you can paste the URL into your existing Chrome browser and the application will run.
Most importantly, you will not be able to view logs in your IDE but within the Chrome browser you can open the development tools. Instructions are as follows:
Press Ctrl+Shift+I (Windows/Linux) or Cmd+Option+I (macOS), or right-click 
on the page and select Inspect. 

With the development tools open select the "Console" tab and you can observe your logs.

This is a good trick, @thenry. I noticed the console shows my logs if have generated by print() function but not those with developer.log('message'). thumbs up.

Very interesting. Thanks for sharing!
